# Getting apache2 303 error while installing Moodle

Tags: moodle, apache2.4

I try installing Moodle 3.11 on Alt Linux. I run install.php, configure the DB configs, and get 303 error from apache2 access_log. [Apache2 access_log screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nhBI.png)

The DB on the other virtual machine, from moodle machine i have access to the DB machine. But if i installing Moodle on machine which has DB, it will install without any error, so im sure that no problems with DB. Im think i do something wrong with the apache httpd2.conf file.

And also im sure that moodle config.php fule is fine.

[Apache2 httpd2.conf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdIKq.png)

I use php8.0, apache2.4, PostgreSQL-server.

I tried to change apache httpd2.conf file and php files according to Moodle installation recommendations from internet. But it will no effects.

Comment: Is your server behind your proxy? Did you check your firewall rules? You did launch your install.php with the apache user? (www-data)

Comment: Yes, its all right with the server. Launch the install.php with linux user, but i almost run apache with him... so, it should be fine with that.

Comment: normally you should use this command if you installed your moodle correctly             # sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php install.php

Comment: i'd also advise to use its help with php install.php --help . I can't say for sure, but i believe you should use arguments to accept the licence among others

Comment: I realise i was talking about install_database.php. Did you try to create your config.php yourself (without install.php) and then use install_database.php ? Here's the command i use for this : sudo -u www-data /usr/local/applis/php/bin/php install_database.php --agree-license --adminuser=admin --adminpass=admin     And beside that, did you check the user on your DB has the sufficient rights ?

Comment: Yes, DB user has enought rights to create/edit tables and etc. No, i dont try to create config.php yourself and use install_database.php. worth a try, thanksю